# How to generate java code from 'processing language'

Tags: android, processing

Ive downloaded the processing files of an android application(Here is the link http://www.gwoptics.org/processing/mobile/BouncingBall/) and i try to compile on processing but i get these 2 errors:

No library found for android.content.res

Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

I want to generate the whole java from this project so i can use some of its parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things that could be messing you up here... Let's go through them:

First you need to make sure you are running the PDE in the Android Mode - in Processing 2.0+ (recommended for Android development) you need to manually install the modes, with the menu item being located in the top right corner or your code window (it says "java" as the default). If you don't have Processing 2.1, download it from https://processing.org/download/?processing

Assuming you actually want to compile and run this code - or the code from another project in which you  use some parts from this - you will also need the Android SDK. A link to that - and other various setup details that you should be sure to read - is located on the Wiki at http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android

Having both of those variables set - being in Android mode and directing Processing to a valid and up to date install of the SDK (which it will ask you to help locate as soon as you switch to Android mode) will allow all of the native Android libraries from the SDK to be found.

Also, it should be pointed out that the source code *IS* Java, in the form of Processing (which as I think you understand, is a large library built on top of Java). But you can use the PDE to export a more 'java-esque' version of the source code (that is readable as an Eclipse project, for example) by going to 'File > Export Android Project'

Comment: my pleasure. consider upvoting the answer as well? excited to see what you create!

Comment: Hey again m8. I left this project on pause for a while now. You reminded me of it with your reply:P I have an issue that came up with the compile. I get this two errors and i have no clue why. Any ideas? 

C:\Users\antonis\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\antonis\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Error running javac.exe compiler 

Line 720: <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">

Line 734: fork="${need.javac.fork}"

Comment: Can you post it in a new question, and try to format the error code a bit, so its easier to read ?

Comment: sure. Ill reply here the link as soon as i post it

Comment: Here is the link m8 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989394/how-to-generate-android-code-from-a-processing-project