# How to generate android code from a processing project

Tags: android, processing

Am trying get the complete code for android form this project (http://www.gwoptics.org/processing/mobile/BouncingBall/) And i get 2 errors when i try to compile it on processing.

Here is the output i get:

```
-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
Installed at C:\Users\antonis\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: BouncingBall
Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for BouncingBall...
Project Target:   Android 2.3.3
API level:        10
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\res
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for BouncingBall...
Library dependencies:
No Libraries

------------------
API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Local\Temp\android1250127420012347820sketch\bin\classes

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\antonis\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\antonis\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Error running javac.exe compiler
```

> ```
> The line 720: <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
> The line 734: fork="${need.javac.fork}"
> ```

Comment: Where does `java` point to? If you're using windows type `where java` in cmd

Comment: it points in System32

Comment: More like `where javac`

Comment: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). for javac

Comment: you must set the proper `JAVA_HOME` in `Path`

Comment: indeed it seems that was the problem. thanks guys